# $_SESSION alternative way for memcached

Tags: php, session

I am on a shared hosting server and my I/O always hits it's limit. When I searched about memcached for shared hosting environment, most of them said it is not wise to use it, because of some security reasons. Therefore, I thought about using `$_SESSION` variable to store user's data instead of always reading on the database.

Is this good practice? recommended? advisable? Any suggestions regarding to this question will help me so much.

Comment: For what sort of I/O are you hitting limits?

Comment: read and write type, I don't really know what type it is, what I only know is like this I/OKB/s, I/O usage.

Comment: How many visitors do you have at peak per hour? This sounds really strange to me. If you REALLY hit HDD read/write limits then moving sessions wont help to much, they are really small.

Comment: I expect that you mean that the input and output on your network connection is capped

Comment: on average 100/per day, yeah I have a limit of 512KB/s (temporarily).

Comment: Well you can reduce writes to the file system, perhaps by placing session data in RAM. But note that the default Php session handler uses files.

Answer (score 0):

It is very common to store some user data in $_SESSION but it depends what data. You can easily store userId, username and some other non confidential data.

If you have database on this shared hosting you may create table that uses Memory engine, so whole the data in that table wil be placed in memory. The problem is that on a server restart this data will be lost and you have to fill it again. But in the end you receive something like memcache :)

You can post here what kind of data you want to store for a more accurate answer.

Comment: Is it okay to store user's: id, username, email, picture. I can only store in sessions per user right? So I can't use it for something like query results?

Comment: Yes you can store this kind of data, but for the picture it will be only possible to store string data (path to the image). But I would advise you to store only image name and generate the dir path to the image (if it is possible of course)

Comment: Does this make my I/O usage lessen?

Comment: It always depends on how many users you have online, but I doubt that it will hit your I/O much. You can calculate the average size of data that you will store in SESSION (you now the type of data and its length).

Comment: As of now, I always hits my I/O limit.

Comment: Even by using session for this data?

Comment: It's placed on the memory but when I fetch it I will also use database,

Comment: What are your concerns about using database?

Comment: well, my I/O usage always hits the limit and most of the cases, database is the natural cause of it, though I can't use memcached as I explained in my question, I am looking for an alternative and that is $_SESSION.

Comment: so what is the problem with memory table in DB ... it will avoid any I/O operations.

Comment: oh, so the memory table in DB will act like a memcached so I can save datas from there temporarily?

Comment: It will work much the same as memcache, yes. Give it a try. It`s not the perfect solution but given these limitations ... :)